# Eclipse IDE error,cmd shows "“Java.lang.classnotfoundexception:version”"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Does anyone know what should I do after I delete all java program( java SE and eclipse IDE for Java Developer ) and then reinstall them over and over again almost the whole day? But it still can't work when i tried to write Java.

It did successfully install jave when I typed javec at cmd, but then I found cmd show that

`Java.lang.classnotfoundexception:version` after I typed `java version`.

And then I open eclipse IDE for Java Developer, the error occurred as below:

`An error has occurred. See the log file C:\eclipse\configuration\1528876404969.log`

And it did change the number when I reopen it, such as 1528881289007.log

Already installed: `jdk-10.0.1` and `jre-10.0.1`, and add the path at environment variables under **window 10 64bits**.

It would be appreciate for taking your time for answering my question.

Comment: The commad line is `java -version` (note the `-`). Without the `-` you are just asking java to run a class called `version` which doesn't exist. What is in the log file? What version of Eclipse are you installing? You need Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) for Java 10

Comment: The version I download was " eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64", the log file " org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.core [57]" and extra...                                                                                                             I already deleted it and then install the version you suggested Oxygen.3a(4.7.3a) "eclipse-SDK-4.7.3a-win32-x86_64", and it works. Thank you very much. :) grep-449